# How to set responsive iframe height without css (html only)

Tags: html, iframe, weebly

I'm looking to `iframe` in a web form that has variable height depending on the page of the form user is on, so that it will be responsive on mobile too

By setting the width it seems to display appropriately, however setting the height as shown in the `HTML` below seems to cut off all but the top of the form.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://credit.omnisourcetech.com/mcgggg?affiliate=mcgggg&deposit=200&card=elite" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" />
```

Because of the nature of how this form will be embedded (into a Weebly site using the custom `HTML` option), it is not feasible to use `CSS` or `javascript` to accomplish this.

Comment: You can still use the inline style attribute with an iframe tag to add css.

Comment: So you want the iframe to be as high as its contents?

Answer (score 2):

You can incorporate "style" into your iframe tag like so:

```
<iframe style="width:300px;height:40%;color:blue;">
```

Then just type like you would within a normal  tag or a css file